# Find what words were added and removed to string, including duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So I have a problem with filtering out what words were added and removed to string if one of the added words is already present in modified string. Function below corretly finds what words were added with duplicates, but after removing any word it counts shifted words as they were added.

Here is some code, "stringAfterModification" is passed argument:

```
const string = "I went to the mall"
const stringAfterModification = "I went to the mall and left mall" || "I to the mall"
const addedValue = stringAfterModification.split(' ')
        .filter((t, index) => stringAfterModification.split(' ')[stringAfterModification .split(' ').indexOf(t)] !== t
            || string.join(' ').split(' ').indexOf(t) !== index).join(' ');
const removedValue = string.join(' ').split(' ').filter(t => !stringAfterModification .split(' ').includes(t)).join(' ');
```

I can filter out that word added are "and" and "left", and if I remove something the removedValue will corretly list out only "went", but then addedValue will list out everything after "went", because their indexes changed. Unfirtunately I cannot ignore this case, because user can add another word that is already present, without there would be no issue here. How can I fix that so addedValue and removedValue are correct regardless if I've added ro removed something?

Comment: In what order do you want `addedValue` and `removedValue`? Does it matter? This sounds a bit like the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) but for lists of strings instead of lists of characters. If order doesn't matter, it can be done by comparing histograms.

Comment: It does matter later, because word can be added anywhere in the string, so after getting what words were added and what removed I create a map with index, word before and word after. But I can manage that with addedValue and removedValue in random order

Comment: I think you first need to clarify the problem before we can give a solution. `bla bla` → `bla bla bla`. Which word was added? `bla bla bla` → `bla bla`. Which word was removed? `foo bar` → `bar foo`. Which word was added, which was removed?

Comment: The problem is that I can make my function work for adding and removing items without acounting for duplicates, or work with duplicates, but crash when removing something - I don't know how to make it work for all cases

Comment: You're not getting any answers because you never completely described what you _want_ your code to do. So we don't know what "work" means except "not crash".

Comment: I think I did - I've explained the issue and said what I want the code to do - properly list added and removed words regardless of shifted indexes or duplicate words that were already present in base string